# Take screenshot with context menu open

Tags: screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of an application with the context menu open.

However, pressing <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> on my keyboard doesn't seem to work with the context menu open. It works fine when it's closed - the result appears in `~/Pictures/Screenshots`.

Other screenshot applications usually require to click a button to capture, which causes the context menu to close.

I'd be most grateful for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Screenshot tool application, set a Delay of a few seconds so you will have the time to click with the mouse and the context menu to open for the moment the app grabs the screenshot. [image]

[image]

Comment: That's useful thanks!
I found the naming format of time is different when activated by app ( hh.mm.ss ) and hotkey ( hh-mm-ss ). Is it a mismatch or designed by intent?

Comment: No idea, the dots are more human readable, but the dashes is programming like and bit more filesafe. If you are really curious about it - you can ask into elementary github by posting an issue but I can't say which naming is better - probably they are done by different developers

Comment: For the record, this limitation was reported in the screenshot tool's repository ([elementary/screenshot#130](https://github.com/elementary/screenshot/issues/130)), but it needs to be fixed upstream — most likely by moving to Wayland.